# How to Auto-Scale Queue System?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, queue, scaling, forge

I am on forge and using laravel horizon. I can easily scale our workers on forge but our demand fluctuates.

I don't want to use redis for queue because of ram limitation. I want to auto-scale our workers and queue system.

What do you guys suggest?